# VBA Excel Paste works, PasteSpecial does not

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am trying to export ranges (as csv) from a multisheet spreadsheet by copying and pasting to another sheet. This works perfectly for the Paste function, but not for the PasteSpecial function.

This is fine:

```
Sheets("Company").Select
  Range("Company_Data").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "D:\Documents and Settings\Charles\Development\G4H Dev\Book3.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

But this returns Error 1004

```
`Sheets("Output").Select
  Range("Output_Data").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "D:\Documents and Settings\Charles\Development\G4H Dev\Book2.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I have tried a variety of options including

```
format:=xlPasteValues
```

but nothing I can find either in the MS documentation of my own reference books appears to give anything but the most cursory (and unhelpful) treament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `PasteSpecial` that uses `xlPasteValues` applies to a `Range` object, not the Worksheet version:

```
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Consistency would be a wonderful thing (meaningful error messages running it second, and adequate documentation third).